# How to handle a mouse click on a WPF datagrid cell in C# that depends on the row and column clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here's a picture of my WPF datagrid:
[image]
It has been produced with this XAML:

```
        <Grid x:Name="LinkedInUsersDataGrid" Margin="54 0">
        <DataGrid x:Name="LinkedInUsersLatestDetails" 
                  Style="{DynamicResource LinkedInDataGridStyle}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  GridLinesVisibility="None">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User name" Binding="{Binding UserName}" Width="120" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="LinkedIn profile id" Binding="{Binding LinkedInProfileId}" Width="150"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Primary email" Binding="{Binding PrimaryEmail}" Width="180"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Actions" Binding="{Binding View}" Width="60" Foreground="#0073b1" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Edit}" Width="60" Foreground="#0073b1" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Delete}" Width="60" Foreground="#0073b1" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

I would like to trigger the opening of a new XAML page to View or Edit the details pertaining to the selected row depending on the specific cell clicked.  I have googled extensively but cannot figure out how to capture the click event and use the cell clicked to know which user details to load.

Is this possible? Thoughts very much welcomed.

In

Comment: If you bind selecteditem then you have the data for the row that has focus. The row the user clicks. That's one way. The other option is to make the edit column a template and put a button in it. Use a command in that. Bind the datacontext to commandparameter. That gives you a reference to the data object presented to a row.

Comment: Thanks very much Andy, which route would you choose? And forgive me for being new at this, but how do I do the 'binding' part in whichever scenario you would suggest?

Comment: Binding is a HUGE subject. Start reading here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview  You should google and read up on MVVM if you're going to do any commercial wpf.

Comment: bind the datagrid itemsource to ObservableCollection<RowViewModel>, which is a special kind of List<RowViewModel>. the RowViewModel object will contain the properties with UserName, LinkedInProfileId, PrimaryEmail etc. So each RowViewModel will represent a row in your datagrid. And so on.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This may be achieved using [**MVVM**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern).

By the pattern we require 2 helper classes:

```csharp
// notifies UI if some property changed
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

// needed for easy Commands use
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

I assume that you need just to display the data and not to edit it inline. Then `DataGrid` is a kind of heavy redundancy. And to show you various WPF features I've played with `ListView`.

*In MVVM you don't need any interactions with Controls from C# code. Thus I didn't give `Name` to controls. To change something just change the data, controls will be updated automatically via `Binding` and `OnPropertyChanged()` calls.*

Full markup to make everything clear.

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1000" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/><!-- MainViewModel attached here -->
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ProfilesList}" Margin="5">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ListViewButtonStyle">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <Style.Triggers><!-- show buttons in list if MouseOver or Selected-->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"><!-- header markup -->
                            <Grid Margin="6,1" >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,4"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                    </Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="1"/>
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="User name"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="LinkedIn profile id"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Primary email" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Actions"/>
                                <Border Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Border Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <Border Grid.Column="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <ItemsPresenter /><!-- telling Control to insert contents here -->
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListView.Template>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Profile}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </Grid.InputBindings>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UserName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LinkedInProfileId}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding PrimaryEmail}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ListViewButtonStyle}" Content="" Command="{Binding DataContext.EditItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource ListViewButtonStyle}" Content="❌" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
            </ListView.InputBindings>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainViewModel` class

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // fields containing everything but not use it outside of properties
    private ObservableCollection<Profile> _profilesList;
    private ICommand _deleteItemCommand;
    private ICommand _editItemCommand;
    private ICommand _openItemCommand;

    // properties backed by fields
    public ObservableCollection<Profile> ProfilesList
    {
        get => _profilesList;
        set
        {
            _profilesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // notify UI
        }
    }

    public ICommand OpenItemCommand => _openItemCommand ?? (_openItemCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is Profile profile)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(profile.ToString(), "OpenItemCommand");
        }
    }));

    public ICommand DeleteItemCommand => _deleteItemCommand ?? (_deleteItemCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is Profile profile)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(profile.ToString(), "Delete Item?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.No) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                ProfilesList.Remove(profile);
            }
        }
    }));

    public ICommand EditItemCommand => _editItemCommand ?? (_editItemCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is Profile profile)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(profile.ToString(), "EditItemCommand");
        }
    }));

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // initializing the collection with demo values
        ProfilesList = new ObservableCollection<Profile>
        {
            new Profile { UserName = "John Smith", LinkedInProfileId = "jsmith", PrimaryEmail = "jsmith@example.com" },
            new Profile { UserName = "Jane Doe", LinkedInProfileId = "jane", PrimaryEmail = "jdoe@example.org" },
            new Profile { UserName = "Forrest Gump", LinkedInProfileId = "runningguy", PrimaryEmail = "fgump@example.net" }
        };
    }
}
```

You didn't show the data class. I've made my own.

```csharp
public class Profile : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _userName;
    private string _linkedInProfileId;
    private string _primaryEmail;
    public string UserName 
    { 
        get => _userName; 
        set
        {
            _userName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } 
    }
    public string LinkedInProfileId
    {
        get => _linkedInProfileId;
        set
        {
            _linkedInProfileId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string PrimaryEmail
    {
        get => _primaryEmail;
        set
        {
            _primaryEmail = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public override string ToString() => UserName + "\r\n" + LinkedInProfileId + "\r\n" + PrimaryEmail;
}
```

That's all...except code-behind class. Here it is:

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The example is not so big and I give you a chance to explore it without my detailed description but added some comments.

[image: Custom ListView]